# How to perform a POST with a web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-phone-7

My question is rather simple, but I can't find any information about this on the internet.

I am developing a windows phone application and I want to use the web api (from MVC 4) to get, set, and update.

I already made all the GET methods and they work fine. My question is: How can I perform a POST from a url (and add data to my database)?

Something like this: http://someurl.com/api/post/username/parameter1/parameter2

Is this even possible? And otherwise how else can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/344078/ASP-NET-WebAPI-Getting-Started-with-MVC4-and-WebAP?

Comment: Yeah, but I don't know how to perform a post so it runs the code.

Comment: You want to post from a native app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org) for all your WebApi work in Windows Phone.

Believe me when I say that it will save you development time!

(To say the truth, I almost never use WebRequest directly in my apps, and just go ahead with RestSharp...)

Answer (score 0):

There are two alternatives:

[WebClient.UploadStringAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144239%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.UploadStringCompleted += OnUploadStringCompleted;
client.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("http://someurl.com/api/post/username/parameter1/parameter2", UriKind.Absolute), "Data to upload goes here");
```

or

[HttpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetrequeststream%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

There's a complete example on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetrequeststream.aspx).

Hope that helps!

Comment: When I try the above code, it doesn't post. I just want to execute the url in the background. When I enter the url in the browser it executes fine. But how do I do this within Windows Phone?

Comment: If it works through a browser, then your server is not responding to a POST, but to a GET. Have you tried with [`WebClient.DownloadStringAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144202(v=vs.95).aspx)?